# Age between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get all the employees whose age will be 64 between two dates that I specify. Any help would be appreciated.

What I have tried is:

```
SELECT 
    papf.person_id, 
    date_of_birth, 
    first_name, last_name, 
FROM per_all_people_f papf 
WHERE 
    paaf.person_id = NVL(:P_PERSON_ID, paaf.person_id) 
    AND :START_DATE = TO_DATE(:START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    AND :END_DATE = TO_DATE(:END_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Add table definition(s), sample table data and the expected result (both as formatted text).

Comment: @EmileArab, Please edit your question and share all data pointed out by jarlh along with the query.

Comment: I would suggest you to add the example data, and the expected result if possible

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
SELECT person_id, date_of_birth, first_name, last_name FROM per_all_people_f 
WHERE floor(months_between(date START_DATE, date END_DATE) /12)=64;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked:

`SELECT papf.person_id,
        date_of_birth,
        INITCAP (papf.title) || ' ' || papf.first_name || ' ' ||       papf.last_name,
        employee_number,
        assignment_id
     FROM per_all_people_f papf, per_all_assignments_f paaf
     WHERE papf.person_id = paaf.person_id
        AND paaf.person_id = NVL(:P_PERSON_ID, paaf.person_id)
        AND PAPF.BUSINESS_GROUP_ID = NVL(:P_BUS_ID, PAPF.BUSINESS_GROUP_ID)
        AND months_between((:P_START_D), (date_of_birth)) / 12 < 64
        AND months_between((:P_END_D), (date_of_birth)) / 12 >= 64
        AND SYSDATE BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND papf.effective_end_date
        AND SYSDATE BETWEEN paaf.effective_start_date AND paaf.effective_end_date`

Answer (score -1):

Since your query from Oracle, please try this one:

```
SELECT PER.FULL_NAME,
   PER.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
   ROUND(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN('your custom date', PER.DATE_OF_BIRTH)) / 12,
1)
FROM   PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PER
WHERE  TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PER.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND 
PER.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND    ROUND(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN('your custom date', PER.DATE_OF_BIRTH)) / 
12, 1) > 64
```